# pass values to another script through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Below is a piece of code that is placed inside for loop

```
for( some condition will go here )
  {
        echo "<td>
        <a href='event.php?event_id=".$datee2. "&action=Details'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</a>
       </td>";
  }
```

On clicking over it the user gets directed to event.php page and along with it, event_id and action parameters are also carried forward,

but instead of this
i wish to call event.php page to the first page through ajax for this i tried this

```
<script>
function chk()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url: "event.php",
            data:dataString,
            cache:false,
            success: function(html)
                {
                    $('#msg').html(html);
                }
            })  ;
        return false;
    }               
</script>

echo 
"<td>
    <a onclick='return chk()'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</a>
</td>";
```

but its not working, and i also wish yo carry forward event_id and action parameters through ajax to event.php page on every click, can anyone tell how this can be done

Comment: how are you creating your dataString? And in console any errors?

Comment: @GHOST93 it is created within a loop, the data is coming automatically so i need to pick data on the click .. there are no errors in the console

Comment: but where are ID and action from where you can fetch it for ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```
<a href="#" class="myclass" data-id="'.$someID.'" data-action="'.$someAction.'">
```

and js will be

```
$(".myclass").on("click", function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var action = $(this).data("action");

$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    url : "event.php",
    data : {
        "id":id,
        "action":action
    },
    cache : false,
    success : function(html)
    {
        $('#msg').html(html);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: i am getting syntax error at  var id = $(this).data("id");

Comment: @Pn12 Please forgive me as I made some mistakes in hurry, I have edited the code and made a fiddle for you as well hope that will help https://jsfiddle.net/x7fowjyn/

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    url : "event.php",
    data : {
        "event_id":"-id of the event-",
        "action":"-0action paramter-"
    },
    cache : false,
    success : function(html)
    {
        $('#msg').html(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: the values in <td> are inside a loop so i need a way that picks the parameters automatically from the click, i can't define the values manually

Comment: then you can pass the data in JSON format. You have to read the data from td and push it into an array. If you give us access to your code then we would be able to figure it out more clearly

Comment: thats the part i am not able to do it.. i am not able to read and pass the data properly

Answer (score 0):

Build your loop adding a class:

```
echo "<td>
        <a class='anEvent' href='event.php?event_id=".$datee2. "&action=Details'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</a>
     </td>";
```

Then use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.anEvent').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#msg').load($(this).attr('href'));
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data` attributes and `$.post` request, and better if you can avoid the `inline-events` and give your link an identifier (class `ajax-link` in my example because your code will be created from a loop so we don't have to use `id` since id should be unique in same document) then you can use it to attach `click` event to the `a` tag, check the following example  :

**PHP :**

```
"<td>
     <a class='ajax-link' data-event-id=".$datee2." data-action='Details'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</a>
</td>";
```

**JS :**

```
$('body').on('click', '.ajax-link', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).data('action');
    var event_id = $(this).data('event-id');

    $.post(url, {event_id: event_id, action: action}, 
        function(html)
        {
            $('#msg').html(html);
        }
    });
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: there was some syntax error, i edited it and its working now, but the issue is in this line $('#msg').html(html); i need to print the result from event.php page, but i am getting the complete data of same page in <div id="msg">

Comment: Okay add please the content of your `event.php` page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are clicking the link which starts loading event.php.
You should use event.preventDefault() to avoid default action in chk() function.

```
function chk()
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url: "event.php",
            data:dataString,
            cache:false,
            success: function(html)
                {
                    $('#msg').html(html);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
```